# Open file from Google Drive on Mac in Python and using generic path

Tags: python, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to open a file from my Google Drive locally using a generic path name and without using the Google API to access the drive (the setup is difficult in my organisation).

I've tried to use `path = '~/Google Drive/Shared drives/` as the generic path name, which works when reading in pandas dataframes using `pd.read_csv()`, but it does not work when I use `open(path + filename, 'r')` for other files. My understanding is that this is because if the path does not start with a `/` then it assumes you are looking for it locally.

I've also tried using `abspath(expanduser("~/")`, however this doesn't work either as my username is attached to the google drive folder as such `/Users/first.last/CloudStorage/GooleDrive-first.last@organisation.com/Shared drives/`, and exapanding the `~` will only give me `/Users/first.last/`.

Is there anyway to expand `~/Google Drive/` into the full path name, or is there any other way to access this path generically?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to expand `"~/Google Drive/"` into the full path name

Yes.

Use [expanduser()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.expanduser).

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path("~/Google Drive/").expanduser()
print(folder)
```

It sounds like what you really want may be

```
folder = Path("~/CloudStorage/GooleDrive-first.last@org.com/Shared drives/").expanduser()
```

Comment: `folder = Path("~/Google Drive/").expanduser()` only gives me `/Users/first.last/Google Drive`, which isn't the correct path for the Google drive folder. Your second part is correct, however, this isn't generic as I'd have to put my Google account name into it (first.last@org.com).

Comment: pandas manages to parse `~/Google Drive/` correctly, so thought there should be a way for `open()` to do so as well.

Comment: The `~` + `.expanduser()` refers to your `USER` env var. Is pandas parsing some google credentials dot file that you'd like another library to do, as well? Or does `env | grep Google` reveal another env var that you could use?

Answer (score 0):

`~` is literally your user's home folder like `/Users/first.last/`. Its the **same** things. What do you mean by expand `~/Google Drive/`??? It would be `/Users/first.last/Google Drive/`. There is no mistake.

Maybe `~/Google Drive/` is **LINK** to `/Users/first.last/CloudStorage/GooleDrive-first.last@organisation.com/Shared drives/` and actually there is no such folder.

Can you go to folder manually. Choose file and look for absolute path in properties?

As J_H already said looks like you are looking for `"~/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-first.last@org.com/Shared drives/"`